# I'm looking for ideas for a wedding ring

Tags: jewelry

My fiance is looking to get me a custom wedding ring and she's asking me for ideas. I'm not used to wearing anything on my hands so automatically I'm thinking of getting a titanium ring because it'll be light, but in terms of the design, I want it to have a practical use.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for a design that is also practical. My thoughts are somewhere along the lines of the tattoo Adam Savage has that he uses to compare materials to get an idea of the length of a material.

I'm a software developer/engineer by trade so if I can have ideas for practical uses that are related to that I would be grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wear a "practise" engagement ring yourself to become used to ring wearing. I did this and scratched it a lot learning.

Comment: Do you mean cut a slice off a tube and chamfer and smooth the corners ? Easy if you know someone in chemical or refinery plant.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I don't think OP is asking how to *make* a wedding ring, but what design of ring would be practical, to have a secondary use perhaps as a tool.

Comment: This isn't the right site to get ideas for the design of a wedding ring.

Answer (score 0):

**Just For Good Measure Hack:**

I once decided to make myself a 'standard' ring; ie.

- Precise diameter (To use as a scale/size standard - in a picture, say)
- Precise weight (To use as a counterweight on a balance, say)
- Precise thickness (To use for comparison, say)
- Precise electrical resistance
  Now, you could also have some electronics built-in:
- Precise RFID/NFC ([Smart ring](https://www.smartringnews.com/smart-ring-products/cnick)) (To use for passwords, passkeys, say)
- etc.

Unique, Light? Have your design made from carbon fibre, say)

Good Luck.

Comment: I edited the question on the assumption that OP isn't asking how to *make* a ring themself: it will be bought or commissioned  by the fiance.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Yes. Good point. I had the time, facilities (full machine shop), and materials to make my ring(s); but, any suitable design can be manufactured for another person.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium is very impractical for a "do it yourself" project. I think investment casting would produce a professional looking ring. Use traditional gold alloys or possibly Vitalium ( cobalt , chrome). A dental protheses shop may be willing to work with you. You make the ring in wax and they pour a metal casting that is an exact replica.

Comment: I made my first ring out of Cobalt which I though would be cool until I discovered there were health threats associated with the stuff. https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/topics/cobalt/default.html — I removed the ring and retired it to my 'box o' stuff.' I've gone back to bare skin. Best to research unconventional materials and human contact reaction before purchase/manufacture.

Comment: Cobalt is used ( with some chrome ) for internal protheses and dental bridge work. I guess "cobalt" needs to hire better PR people.

Answer (score -1):

When we got married we got celtic knot rings

[image]

Another one we considered was a layered "mokume gane " ring.

[image]

We went with the celtic style, as my partner is of Scotish heritage.

I found that gold wears quickly (I work in the dirt a lot.) I wore it out and lost it in the dirt.  I had a replacement made in silver, we being poor.  As my hands aged, I had to have it expanded a couple times to get it on and off.

Tungsten Carbide will NOT wear out, but they cannot be resized.

[image]

[image]